# How to transform a List<Map<String, Object>> into Map<String, List<Object>> using Java 8

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a list with a map inside and I need to turn it into a map with a list inside.

I have a `List <Map <String, Object >>`
and I need to change it to
`Map<String, List <Object<Object>>>`.

, of course, by passing the data contained in it, matching the keys to the values

There are objects of the Date class in the Object class, this structure was used because it is the result returned by jdbcTemplate.
Now I need to change that to have a date list for each unique String key.

I have a method that takes two columns from a database
and returns `List<Map<String, Object >>`. One column is the username and the second column is the dates on which he was on vacation. I need a data structure that will allow me to match the key (`userId`) with a list of his vacation dates.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getHoliday(String teamLeaderId) {
    String query = "SELECT  H.userid, date FROM Holiday H INNER JOIN Contact C on H.userid = C.UserId INNER JOIN Team T on C.TeamId = T.team_id WHERE team_leader = ? AND isApproved = 0";
    return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, teamLeaderId);
}
```

I'm using Java 8.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Code and description added into the question

Comment: So, didn't try to implement the transformation `List<Map<String, Object>>` → `Map<String, List<Object>>` yourself? If you did share this code as well.

Comment: Of course I tried, but I failed.

Comment: Ok, failure is a part of a process, if you had a satisfactory solution there would be a question, right? Attempt always bring value to the question, and every question on SO is expected to demonstrate a research effort (see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Every questioner is encouraged to share their attempt, it not a recommendation, but rather a requirement.

Comment: Okay, got it. I admit that I have not read it so far. Thank you. As for my question, I would like to know if what I want to do is possible at all and if my search for a solution makes sense. I tried the foreach loop, I tried to substitute MultiValuedMap for Map, but that also did not give a satisfactory result.

Comment: Sure, it's doable, even without multimap using standard JDK Collections. Consider improving the question by sharing one of your attempts.

Comment: Although, I posted the solution. You're still advised to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to do so using Collectors.toMap to convert the List to Map
, Here a small exemple to how to do it.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object >> list =  new ArrayList <Map <String, Object >>(){{ // just to simulate the result
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                final Integer finalI = i + 1;
                final Integer simulateID = (finalI % 3) + 1;

                add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, finalI);
                    put("userid", simulateID.toString() );
                    put("date", cal.getTime());
                }});
            }
        }};

        Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = list
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> (String) e.get("userid"),
                    e -> new ArrayList<Object>(){{ add(e.get("date")); }},
                    (v1, v2) -> {
                        v1.addAll(v2);
                        return v1;
                    }
            )
        );

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

But before using something like that maybe is better take a look in this article to see if it fit to your needs
https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/06/13/jdbc-template-one-to-many.html

Answer (score 0):

## Plain for-loop

You can group *entries* having identical *keys* using Java 8 method [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = // initilizing the list

Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, Object> map: listOfMaps) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        result
            .computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

If you don't feel comfortable with Java 8 features than you can replace `computeIfAbsent()` with the lines shown below (note that used of `computeIfAbsent()` is preferred over `putIfAbsent()` because function would be evaluated lazily, meanwhile `putIfAbsent()` would create a new empty List with every call):

```
result.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
result.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue());
```

## Stream API

You can address this problem using Stream API:

- Flatten the *entries* of each Map using `flatMap()` operation;
- Group the *entries* having the same *key* using collector `groupingBy()` and apply the combination of collectors `mapping()` and `toList()` as a downstream.

That's how it might look like:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = // initilizing the list

Map<String, List<Object>> result = listOfMaps.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Plain Java**

```java
public static <T> Map<String, List<T>> convert(List<Map<String, T>> items) {
    Map<String, List<T>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<String, T> item : items)
        for (Map.Entry<String, T> entry : item.entrySet())
            map.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getValue());

    return map;
}
```

**Stream**

```java
public static <T> Map<String, List<T>> convert(List<Map<String, T>> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .flatMap(item -> item.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                               Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                                  Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to change the database query and the return type. This solved the problem and there was no need to change the structure. The link https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/06/13/jdbc-template-one-to-many.html turned out to be very helpful.

Thank you for all the hints, they will definitely be useful in the future.